# Did Chapman ever find a cigarette carrying roach?

Tags: plot-explanation, orange-is-the-new-black

In the first episode of season 2 of Orange Is The New Black, we see Piper Chapman being moved to a prison in Chicago.  When she first arrives, and gets assigned to her cell, she ends up stepping on Yoda, the cigarette carrying roach that carried cigs from the general population to Solitary.  Her cell mates tell her that she has to find them another roach, and we proceed to see her walking around the yard, and inside the prison looking for another roach to present to them to take Yoda's spot.

My question is, did she ever find a cigarette carrying roach?  I know when she was in the holding cell, after Alex had left, she saw a roach carrying a cigarette on it's back, but that was the end of hearing about that storyline.  Was this ever resolved?  Do we find out later in the season or another season?  Or was this just simply a "filler" storyline to make her time in Chicago more "interesting"?

Comment: This seems like it would be answerable simply by watching the rest of the series.

Comment: It's like the chicken. Sort of a distraction for her from her crisis every time. While talking to Polly on the phone she got distracted by the chicken and while talking to Alex she got distracted by the roach. Well this is just my interpretation. They haven't shown anything yet so we won't know until it comes up again in the series.

Answer (score 3):

Surely you've answered your own question here.

*Did Chapman ever find a cigarette carrying roach?*

And then:

*I know when she was in the holding cell, after Alex had left, she saw a roach carrying a cigarette on it's back, but that was the end of hearing about that storyline.*

There's your answer! She did see one in her cell. Of course, soon after she left that prison and there was no need to continue the storyline with many of those inmates (or indeed Yoda, the cockroach).

But **yes, she did indeed see a cigarette carrying roach.**